# Wireless internet missing. No icon or settings

Tags: release-hera, settings, wifi, wingpanel, internet

### [image]

[image: nerty]

**I just installed Hera.**
As you can see, there is no wifi in settings.
as you can also see, the wifi icon seems to have been replaced by the "wired" symbol on the top bar. I cant turn on any of the options on that symbol

Please note that **i have no access to the internet at all** on the laptop.
*i do, however, have a pc that is connected to wifi.* (the one im posting on)
*i also have a usb flash drive.* (the one i used to transfer the screenshot files.)

OK, ive found the specs:

HP 14-DK0002DX

14″ Laptop (AMD A9 with Radeon R5, 4GB RAM, 128GB SSD)

[image]

I have wifi now via usb tethering on my phone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out myself following these instructions:
https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de/blob/current/README.md

Answer (score -1):

Checking the issue with these two commands to find out what Wi-Fi adapter you are using and do you have any information about missing firmware.

```
sudo lspci
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Getting Internet

We need a temporary internet connection to fix WiFi. Ways to connect :

Connect USB cable and use USB Tethering in your phone to connect your computer to the internet (through phone's cellular data/WiFi)Use wired ethernet cable for connecting to internet.

Prerequisite

You should install the corresponding header of your kernel. Open terminal and type:

This as first:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Next, install the packages necessary for building :

This as second:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms
```

Then type in terminal as third:

```
cd
```

And then type this as fourth command in order, everything in one line.

```
git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

Type this as fifth command:

```
sudo dkms add rtlwifi_new
```

Type this as sixth command:

```
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Restart laptop.

If you will have issue with typing commands one by one, use this one-liner:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` && sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms && cd  && git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git && sudo dkms add rtlwifi_new  && sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

And then restart laptop.

Other methods described here:

https://subinsb.com/install-realtek-d723-wifi-driver-linux/

Comment: I tried this: `git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git` But it asks for a login and password.

Comment: sorry for the late comment, but the link appears to be broken. When i run the command, it asks for my login and password, and even when i answer it properly, it has an error and fails.